# How to get real-time status updates of Django REST API task?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, async-await, celery, django-channels

I have a Django REST API. When i hit GET request on this API, this executes my six python selenium bots one by one, And then returns the status of all bots with 200 code.

The problem is that bots take too long to execute, so i want the status of first bot when it completes, then status of second bot, etc in the same GET request like Real Time updates.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answers will help you because your questions aren't detailed.
Consider using Django Signal.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/